# Can't retrieve Ajax Request

Tags: php, ajax

I'm not too familiar with Ajax but I believe I grasp the basics. So I'm sending an id which I retrieve from an element to a php page but I can't seem to retrieve the id being send.

My javascript:

```
function ListPart(part) {
        var imgdata = part;
        $.ajax({
            url: "components.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { id : imgdata },
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(imgdata) {
                alert(imgdata);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

My components.php:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["id"])) {
        echo $_POST["id"];
    } else {
        echo "not found";
    }
?>
```

Am I missing something small? Also I would like to know in that alert(imgdata) I get the whole document's html and not just the id? Is there a reason for this?

PS: The "not found" is not even being displayed. Although the alert in the success function does execute.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you are missing `exit` at the end

Comment: can you paste the html code i mean the complete page

Comment: @ancientgeek The receiving page html? The 'part' variable in ListPart is just the id from a html image element. Can't see why the html is needed here?  - gautam3164 can you maybe be a bit more specific to where to add the exit statement?